# Ionic Video Player Plugin Causing App Crash on Android 10 and Above

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

I am attempting to integrate the Capacitor Video Player plugin into my project.

The plugin documentation can be found here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v4/native/video-player.

However, I've encountered an issue where the video player crashes on Android devices with an OS version above 10.

Comment: try this: https://github.com/jepiqueau/capacitor-video-player